# "Connectivity failure" using Visual Studio 2015's Remote GDB Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, gdbserver

I am trying to build and test [Linux applications using Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/), but I couldn't get the remote GDB Debugger to work. Here's what I've done:

I've set up a virtual machine running on Xubuntu with the IP 192.168.1.7 (bridge connection) and run
gdb server with the command:
`gdbserver --multi 192.168.1.7:4378`

On Visual Studio, I clicked on Remote GDB Debugger and here is what I've typed in:

```
 Host name: 192.168.1.7  
 Port: 4378   
 User name: test  
 Authentication type:
 Password Password: test
```

When I connect, gdbserver on Xubuntu shows:

```
 Remote debugging from host 192.168.1.5
```

On the Visual Studio however, nothing happened until after a while, it says

```
 Connection failure. Please make sure host name and port number are correct.
```

I know for certain that the gdbserver did receive the remote debugging request, but I don't know why nothing happens on Visual Studio.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?